# Eliminate non-visible characters perl

Tags: perl, character-encoding

I have a perl variable that is being read in from another script's STDOUT:

```
$var = `someScript.sh`
print $var    <---- Prints "somestring"
```

However, the variable contains more than "somestring".  There are 15 more characters on the front of the variable (special and not-special but hidden) that don't show when I print.

```
length($var)  <--- Returns a number 10-15 larger than "somestring" has chars
```

I can eliminate the special characters like so:

```
$var =~ s/[^[:print:]]+//g
```

But it appears that there are also non-special characters that are revealed once the special characters have been removed:

```
print $var   <---- Displays "0;<hostname>somestring" 
            (where <hostname> is the system hostname)
```

Is there a way to eliminate both the special characters AND the non-special characters that were being hidden?  I want to be able to use $var as the key of a hash, and then reference it by "somestring"

```
$hash{$var} = 123
print $hash{'somestring'}
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Could you perhaps show us exactly what the output is? E.g. with `use Data::Dumper; print Dumper($var)`.

Comment: or just run SomeScript.sh in your shell and pipe it into `hd` (`hexdump -C`).  or even `cat -A`.  you've already accepted an answer but i'm interested anyway....and i'll guess that SomeScritp.sh is outputting Escape codes for controlling a terminal (vt100 or whatever).

Comment: As Moritz and Craig say, it would be wise to find out exactly what the characters are that need to be removed, rather than throwing regexes at it until it "looks right"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Can we assume that the characters you want to remove are before the non-printable characters ?

If so, maybe something like

```
$var =~ s/.*[^[:print:]]+//;
```

could work ?

Comment: -1: Remove all non-newlines with at least one following non-printable everywhere? If the string had a newline at the end this would delete the whole string. Why the `/g` modifier? Why no anchor at the start of the string? It would be wise to find out exactly what the characters are that need to be removed

Comment: You're right. Removed the totally useless `/g` (kept from the copy/paste). And I was assuming also that any terminal \n would be chomped. (but I think that an additional anchor is useless too)

Comment: I just wanted to cleanse the file of characters that DBD::CSV has issues with so I used $var =~ s/[^[:print:]\r\n]//g;